# Enabling CORS Sprint Boot RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors, spring-restcontroller

What will be the result of the following:

Is set at class level:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://hostname", maxAge = "3000")
```

And at method level, I have:

```
@CrossOrigin
```

Will the method be applied with the origin and maxAge, or will it take all the defaults from @CrossOrigin?

I understand that a mixed configuration can be applied to a method if it's annotated at class level and method level - But this set up seems backward to me

Answer (score 1):

```
Will the method be applied with the origin and maxAge, or will it take all the defaults from @CrossOrigin?
```

It will use both and combine configurations from both global and local annotations. When combining non null values are taken. So your Class level annotation has values and Method level annotation has no values then Class level values will be applied.

Check [CorsConfiguration.combine](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#combine-org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration-) method for more details.